# Match phonebook contacts in Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, relation

I want to make an option in my app that shows all contacts who are using this application. Its just comparable with the WhatsApp contact tab which is showing there names,status and picture.

I had the idea that I just upload the phonebook contacts with there phone number into my database and I would be able to match these contacts later.

Example :
If person "A" has the phone number of B in his phonebook(which is in the database) AND If person "B" has the number of "A" in the phonebook (which is also in Database) THEN match them and make them Visible as friends in the App.

I wanted to realize this through mysql. BUT now theres my problem :

What if the person A or B did not saved his friend with for example a area code or country code but the other did ? So they wouldn't be able to be matched in my database.

**Is there a way to normalize the phone numbers before uploading them into my database ? That means that the app automatically adds there area code or location code ?**

Comment: Looked at any of those? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=normalize+phone+number